# Как игнорировать роль @everyone?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я хочу игнорировать роль @everyone при рандомной выдачи ролей [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: опишите проблему по подробнее , и покажите код

Comment: зачем вам нужен код,у меня была проблема с @everyone а не в коде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
guild = ctx.message.guild
roles =  [role for role in guild.roles[1:]]
```

Выведет все роли которые есть на сервере без роли `@everyone`, думаю дальше сами додумаете